# How to get Index settings in NEST v7.x

Tags: nest, elasticsearch.net

In previous versions of NEST/Elasticsearch.Net (v5.x), we could use below code to get index settings.

```
Client.LowLevel.IndicesGetSettings<JObject>(currentIndexName)
```

However, these methods seems to have been dropped in v7.X. What will be equivalent in V7.x?

Atleast on the Java side, there is a Get Settings API with some proper documentation. I dont see anything similarly provided on NEST.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-get-settings.html

If anyone is aware of equivalent api and/or any available documentation, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `client.Indices.GetSettingsAsync` method.

Here is a simple app:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(new[] {new Uri("http://localhost:9200")});
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
            .DefaultIndex("index_name")
            .EnableDebugMode()
            .DisableDirectStreaming()
            .PrettyJson();
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        await client.Indices.DeleteAsync("index_name");
        await client.Indices.CreateAsync("index_name", d => d.Settings(s => s.NumberOfShards(20)));

        var getIndexSettingsResponse = await client.Indices.GetSettingsAsync("index_name");

        Console.WriteLine(getIndexSettingsResponse.Indices["index_name"].Settings.NumberOfShards);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
20
```

Hope that helps.